# Monitor data flowing between BHO and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

Is there a way to monitor data flowing between BHO and IE?
I am writing one BHO and its giving some issues . I have tried tools like fiddler which can monitor traffic between server and IE but can I monitor traffic flowing between BHO and IE.

I am mostly interested in some tool.

Comment: What do you mean by data flow? There is no 'traffic' between IE and BHO in classic way (there's no TCP/UDP, IPC or similar way of communication). BHO is just DLL (actually COM component) that resides inside browser process.

Comment: What language is your BHO written in?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a Windows debugger to debug this type of problem.  WinDBG/Visual Studio/etc.

Answer (score 0):

To know how to properly debug a BHO project in e.g. VS2010, as is suggested by EricLaw, you could refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086891/how-to-debug-c-sharp-bho-project-in-visual-studio-internet-explorer/24206945#24206945).

I found many answers on this topic to be incomplete, inaccurate or not properly demonstrated and tried to fix that situation.