# Using breakpoints in visual studio 2010 for BHO in IE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-studio-2010, bho

I'm developing a BHO in Visual Studio 2010. So far I've managed to register the BHO and get visual studio launch IE when I hit debug. The BHO works as expected but unfortunately break points that I set are never hit. Is there something that needs to be configured first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have registered the 'debug' dll and not the release one (that didn't contain debugging information) ?

Personally I created a scrip that register the dll and this script is executed each time I compile (post-processing).

Hope that help !

**EDIT:**

**I'm using VS 2008 but could you check if your configuration correspond to mine ?**
[image]

Comment: Not sure at all! I'll try registering again making sure that it's the debug dll.

Comment: OK, registered the dll again, making sure that is was the debug dll that got registered. So far, no luck. BTW, could you share that script? It would be a huge timesaver.

Comment: Can you check if your configuration is like mine ? specially 'about:blank' (really important) and the 'Enable unmanaged code debugging' flag ?

Comment: Ok, that made a difference, I was using 'Start browser with URL:' rather than 'Start external program:'. I do have the 'Enabled unmanaged code debugging' set. It's now saying it can't find the PDB. There is a PDB in the debug directory with the dll, not sure how to tell it to look there though.

Comment: After following some other advice I'm now starting IE first then using attach to process to start the debugging. The breakpoints now appear valid (now ! next to them) but they're still never hit.

Comment: OK, so they're working! As I said above I now start IE first and then 'Attach to process'. When shown the process list you'll see 2 entries for IE. You need to select the one with a 'Type' of 'Managed'. Once you've done that you should be good to go. In my case I refreshed the IE window and triggered the onDocumentComplete event that I have a handler for. Alois: many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your welcome ! Good to know if I have to update the project one day to VS2010.

Comment: These steps (starting IE outside of VS) worked for me as well in VS2010 with IE8. Note that if you have changed IE's settings to enable script debugging, then the entry under "Attach to process" will show two types, Script and Managed. You have to then explicitly set the code type to "Managed (v4.0)".

Also, I didn't need to check "Enable unmanaged code debugging".

Comment: This answer is very incomplete. More is needed to properly attach the debugger. I have added a reference to a full description below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4.0 the debugger won't attach properly to IE.  So here is what you do:

Run Visual Studio as an administrator.

Add the following code to your BHO:

```
Debugger.Break();
```

Experiment a bit with placement; I'd say set it after the site is set.

Run Internet Explorer independently of Visual Studio.  As in don't launch IE from within Visual Studio.  When IE runs you will get a crash window (the result of the code above); that's when you can attach Visual Studio to IE.  Done and done.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086891/how-to-debug-c-sharp-bho-project-in-visual-studio-internet-explorer/24206945#24206945) for a complete description of steps needed to properly attach the debugger and debug a BHO project.