# Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger not finding already open instances

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a C# console application program that is called by an external program which provides it with its command line parameters.  In order to ease debugging, I've created a conditional method which I call immediately in `Main()`:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
static void BreakIfInDebugMode()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```

In the external program, when I want to debug, I point the external call to the `bin\Debug` location of my .exe, the Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger window pops up, and I select the instance of Visual Studio that I'm currently using to do development.

Except, starting today, currently running instances of Visual Studio are not appearing.  I only get the option to start a new instance.  Even the new instance I launch through the Debugger prompt doesn't show up when I leave it running.  This is a huge hassle, since I have an already running instance with the project open, and breakpoints already set around the code I want to debug.

I have noticed that it takes a longer than usual time from the "Close the program/Debug the program" to the "Select an instance of Visual Studio dialog".  Any solutions for why the debugger selection is not finding my already running debuggers?

Edit: After performing a reboot, the expected behavior was restored.  It would still be nice to fix via less drastic measures.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your VS instance is running elevated.

Comment: @HansPassant Checked in process explorer and all instances are running at "Medium" integrity level. Also, the instances spawned by the Just-In-Time Debugger window don't show up in subsequent runs.

Comment: A full reboot "fixed" it, but still no idea what caused it in the first place.  Edited the question to include this new (but not shocking) development

Comment: @HansPassant Incidentally, I am running into this as well trying to debug an old BHO project. Any more ideas? I am running VS2010 as Admin but this was never a problem before... [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086891/how-to-debug-c-sharp-bho-project-in-visual-studio-internet-explorer/24206945#24206945)

Comment: Please accept http://stackoverflow.com/a/42692925/55721

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the process is running as admin, and VS is not. This was my problem.

Comment: This was my exact problem

Answer (score 5):

Please check if you have enabled the check boxes named 'Managed' and/or 'Native' in visual studio under:

**Tools->Options->Debugging->Just-In-Time**

I ran into this problem recently where i had accidentally disabled these check boxes. It may not be relevant to your problem as it is working after the reboot. I am just posting this so that others may find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the two different answers already posted on this page, seems like this issue is having a (short) comeback. But in this time it's as a **real bug** in `Visual Studio 2017` early versions.

Anyway - No need to panic, it's **already fixed** in `Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3 preview 2`.
Just make sure your'e using this version or higher.

See [Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41363/if-you-do-a-debuggerlaunch-in-your-c-app-your-work.html#reply-container-67026) for more details.

Comment: Vs2020: I accidently choose "New Instance" instead of open solution.  Now the Open solutions do not show in the available debuggers list.  Just brilliant Microsoft!